# How to configure Windows to open CSV files directly in the browser?

Tags: windows, browser, csv, file-types

How can I configure Windows and/or Internet Explorer so it opens online CSV files (files on the internet) directly in the browser without asking to download them?

I want the same behavior of TXT files for CSV files as well.

I'm using Windows Vista Home Premium and IE9.

Comment: **You do understand the files are actually downloaded right in either case right?**

Comment: @Ramhound, that's a no-brainer. I just want the browser to show the content of the CSV files right in the browser window like it would do with TXT files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to Vista, IE9 or online CSVs, so it's up to you to test this.

Save the following as **Add_CSV.reg** and double-click to merge into the registry:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/csv]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/csv]
"CLSID"="{25336920-03F9-11cf-8FD0-00AA00686F13}"
"Encoding"=hex:08,00,00,00
```

For best results reboot once before testing. If it doesn't work, saving and merging **Del_CSV.reg** will undo the changes:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\application/csv]

[-HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\MIME\Database\Content Type\text/csv]
```

Comment: Excellent!, It worked right away, no need to reboot.

Answer (score 0):

Right click a CSV -> open with. Tick always use this program and select IE.

Comment: But I dont want to open local files with the browser. I want the same behavior of TXT files.

Comment: Ah, you mean if you click on 'www.example.com/file.csv' in a link, you want it to open within the browser instead of asking you to download it?

Comment: Exactly. I'm going to clarify the question.

Comment: If you do want Justin suggests and make it the default program you should get the behavior you want.

Comment: I have a feeling that it would ask 'do you want to save this file or open with... IE', then show the download dialog and then open in IE when it's done, where as the behaviour he wants is to have it start loading straight away in IE like a text file; i.e. you load a 5MB text file it will partially load and you can read it while it continues to download. I don't know how to do that.